# How to print out a DOCX file in java?

Tags: java, printing

i have created some java code that allows me to print png,pdf,jpg etc but i am stuck on docx files and possibly other file types,

currently i am using the code below :

```
 if (extension.equals("txt")) {
            psInFormat = DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.AUTOSENSE;
        } else if (extension.equals("png")) {
            psInFormat = DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.PNG;
        } else if (extension.equals("gif")) {
            psInFormat = DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.GIF;
        } else if (extension.equals("jpg")) {
            psInFormat = DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.JPEG;
        } else if (extension.equals("pdf")) {
            psInFormat = DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.PDF;
        }
```

to determine what the file type is to create the ps of the right input stream for that doc type, could i mod this code to include doc files ?

Comment: My approach would be to see if you can use OpenOffice programmatically to convert the `.docx` to a `.pdf` and then printing that directly.

Comment: Thanks, i can print out pdfs, but sadly for this program it one of the major requirements is to print out doc files

Comment: That's why I said to **convert** the docs into PDFs. I meant that you'd do so on-demand from your application. OpenOffice should be automatable, letting you invoke its features from a Java (or C++) program, but unfortunately that's roughly the extent of how much I know about this. I suggested it because all of the other answers merely point you at libraries that parse `docx` into a data structure that might let you easily modify existing documents, but is a long way from actually printing one.

Comment: Ah thank you that is a great idea, sorry i thought you meant use open office on the desktop before sending, i shall look into that as this might be a great solution

Answer (score 3):

There's no way to do this directly with DocFlavor

Take a look to the POI Project

http://poi.apache.org/hwpf/index.html

Comment: Thanks a lot, shall take a look into it

Answer (score 2):

A better answer than POI is to use docx4j

http://www.docx4java.org/trac/docx4j

The reason for this is because it has all of the API necessary for getting to the different parts of the docx package.

Comment: Thanks a lot, shall take a look into it