# File has not been printed Through Printer device in java

Tags: java, printing, printers

I want to print a file.I wrote this code for doing this.But it does not print my file.
for choose service:

```
      String printerName = "Canon MF4320-4350".toLowerCase();
    PrintService service = null;

    PrintService[] services = PrinterJob.lookupPrintServices();

    // Retrieve a print service from the array
    for (int index = 0; service == null && index < services.length; index++) {

        if (services[index].getName().toLowerCase().indexOf(printerName) >= 0) {
            service = services[index];
        }
    }
```

for printing:

```
    byte[] bytes = null;
    Path path = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath("D:\\Test.docx");
    bytes = Files.readAllBytes(path);
    DocFlavor docFlavor = DocFlavor.BYTE_ARRAY.AUTOSENSE;
    PrintRequestAttributeSet faset = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
    faset.add(new Copies(5));
    faset.add(Sides.ONE_SIDED);
    DocAttributeSet daset = new HashDocAttributeSet();
    daset.add(OrientationRequested.LANDSCAPE);
    daset.add(Sides.ONE_SIDED);
    Doc myDoc = new SimpleDoc(bytes, docFlavor, daset);
    //create the DocPrintJob
    DocPrintJob job = service.createPrintJob();
    job.print(myDoc, faset);
```

Answer (score 1):

That's not how printing works - when Word prints out a `docx` file, it doesn't send the raw bytes of the file to the printer. Instead, it translates the file into low-level printing commands which it sends to the print driver.

The Java print API can handle [2d rendering via drawing commands](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/printing/printable.html), or it allows you to send a raw stream of bytes to the printer, but it's then your responsibility to make bytes the printer understands.

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14861775/how-to-print-out-a-docx-file-in-java), and look at [docx4j](http://www.docx4java.org/trac/docx4j).

Comment: Thank you Adrian,But if I but .txt file here,it does not work either.

Comment: If you intend to print by sending a stream of bytes to the printer, your best reference is the filters used by Linux printing for your printer (https://wiki.debian.org/PrinterDriver/Canon/UFR-II).  I don't think Canon inkjets print plain text without translation to UFR.

Comment: Than you :),Is there another way, apart from sending a stream of bytes to the printer?

Comment: All the techniques for printing are complex: you can generate your own page layout, or run Word, or use a Linux print server to translate formats, or choose a model of printer that natively understands the format you want.