# How can I Print DOCX file in Netbeans using Aspose.words?

Tags: netbeans, printing, docx

Recently, I was working on a project that can print DOCX files in Netbeans. I am new in java so I'm not really familiar with it. I use Aspose.Words but I really don't know how to use it. I watch many tutorials but they are not in NetBeans so I am confused. Thanks a lot in advance for helping me.

This is my code:

```
String dox = path.getText();
    XWPFDocument docx = null;
try {
    docx = new XWPFDocument(POIXMLDocument.openPackage(dox));
    XWPFWordExtractor ext = new XWPFWordExtractor(docx);
    content.setText(ext.getText());
} catch (IOException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(count.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}

PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
job.setPrintable(new OutputPrinter(path.getText()));
boolean doPrint = job.printDialog();
if (doPrint)
{ 
    try 
    {
       job.print();
    }
    catch (PrinterException e)
    {
       // Print job did not complete.
    }
}
```

I tried extracting it but it only gets the content. What I'm trying is to print the whole document just like in the MSWord.

Answer (score 0):

First of all: Why is this a NetBeans question? I can’t see any NetBeans relations, maybe you should change it to Java (at least the tag).

Second: I think your question is a duplicate to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14861775/how-to-print-out-a-docx-file-in-java)